# Start the New Year with a Good Question - fancy joining me?

Tags: discussion

Joe's excellent question here [Are we dead yet?](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/are-we-dead-yet) has prompted me to think about what we can do in 2012 to give SQA some TLC. We're gradually growing in numbers, and visits to the site - but if there isn't regular, good content being added, this site won't become the great resource for test professionals that it deserves to be.

Things have dropped off towards the end of 2011 - let's start 2012 with a bang!

I'm making a personal pledge to post 5 good questions a week throughout January. I feel a bit daunted at the thought - I've only posted 8 questions since the site started! But I think this is the best way to trigger more participation in the site.

Anyone fancy joining me in a pledge?

Comment: Sounds fun, and I hate turning down a challenge!

Comment: Excellent! Welcome aboard Lyndon :) Okay, so who'll be next to throw their hat in the ring?

Comment: For whatever reason, traffc has picked up this week.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that there's nothing wrong with asking a question that you've already answered. It's actually encouraged. Often times, I find myself writing up questions (usually on SO, but here sometimes...) and answer it before I'm done writing it because just talking it out helped me see the problem. I should reconsider scrapping the question, and instead posting it. Then either answering it immediately or waiting a day or two.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, bit of a tricky one for me as I like to put my good questions on the STC. I have been getting a bit more 'techy' recently so maybe I could put some of those here

Comment: Yay! Perhaps you could put the more discussion provoking ones on the STC, and other more techy ones here? Or cross-fertilise by getting some answers here, and then starting a discussion on STC? STC is definitely suited for some stuff that the format on SQA isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, answering my own question with an update on progress:

Two-thirds of the way through, and how'm I doing? Well - not so well. I'm going to have to seriously get my act in gear if I'm going to make 20 questions before the end of the month: so far I've posted 4.

On the bright side, all (apart from the one I just posted) have received answers, and at least one upvote - so they weren't terrible questions. But I was aiming to get a bit more quantity as well - let's see how I do with the rest of the month!

How's everyone else doing? Still time to join in - you don't need to go crazy and commit to 20, what about 3 before the end of Jan? Or what about committing to tweeting 5 questions you like and think deserve more or better answers?

Comment: I don't think I would be able to, but I do commend the focus on quality as well as quantity. It's not like a school paper where we hand something in and settle for a C. The goal is to stimulate further questions and activity, and poor questions don't help that at all. I think you're doing excellent! :-)